# Why is my Graphql project throwing Error: field type must be Output Type but got: undefined

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, graphql-js, apollo

[Github Repo](https://github.com/zbloss/graphql)

I am fetching data from [this espn endpoint](http://games.espn.com/ffl/api/v2/boxscore?leagueId=1150587&seasonId=2017&teamId=5&scoringPeriodId=7)
I am also brand new to GraphQL and am not super familiar with fetching nested information.

In the above github repo, I'm currently working in on the "schema1.js" file and when I run it the console throws Error: Boxscore.teams field type must be Output Type but got: undefined.

Normally I would post the schema1.js below but it is too large to format correctly.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are currently writing your fields as

```
...
teams: new GraphQLObjectType({ ... })
...
```

The correct syntax is

```
...
teams: {
    type: new GraphQLObjectType({ ... })
}
...
```

---

Also, I strongly advise you to not define your types nested like you did ; instead, define them independently :

```
const TeamType = new GraphQLObjectType({ ... });

const BoxscoreType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Boxscore',
  fields: () => ({
    teams: {
      type: TeamType
    },
    ...
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks! As I was building it something did feel off, I'll try to break it down

Comment: What would you do in the case of boxscore > teams > lists? After the "teams" dictionary I'm given two lists, so would I define the TeamType fields as two lists and then need to create a List0Type and List1Type?